# Unable to output flash msg from another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried to use another function/method to redirect & output a notice, but it didn't work. It work fine within its own function.

```
  def delete_sb
    # @sb = SasaranBaru.find(params[:id])
    # @sb.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "fffff"
    render_group("flash msg")
  end

  def render_group(notice)
    logger.debug notice
    flash[:notice] = notice
    if params[:filter]
      filter = prepare_filter_query(params[:filter])
      redirect_to "/groups?#{filter.to_query}", notice: 'okokoko okokokok '
    else
      redirect_to "/groups", notice: 'hehehehe eheheheh'
    end
  end
```

there is no value for flash in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a redirect going on after this code? A flash is only valid for one request and then disappears.

One way to test this is use:

```
flash.keep[:notice]='ffffff'
```

and see if that shows up, but I suspect you are going through another controller in `/group` and redirecting again, losing the flash.

Comment: omg you are correct. theres is another redirect. I missed red a request in the debug